# Powershell Remoting performance

Tags: performance, powershell, remoting

I am managing a lab for a technology conference, and I have a PowerShell script that does some cleanup between sessions, deleting leftover cruft from the desktop, resetting links in the Taskbar, etc. When I run this script "locally", meaning I use a shortcut while logged in as the generic lab user, it takes about 5 seconds to complete. However, when I run the same script using Remoting it takes nearly 10 minutes to complete. And this on a single machine. My worry is that I have 40 machines that need to refresh, and sometimes only 15 minutes total between sessions. The code I am testing with is pretty simple

```
Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine -argumentList: $file, $context –scriptblock {
    param (
        [String]$file,
        [string]$context
    )

    & powershell.exe -noProfile -noLogo -executionPolicy bypass -file $file -context:$context

} -credential:$credential -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
```

So, my question is, is this "normal", or is there some indication of a problem and I should really expect this to work at something closer to "local" speeds? FWIW, I am testing this on a VM.

Additionally, I am using a BallonTip to alert anyone who is sitting at the machine that a reset is happening. This works great when "manually" launching the script. However, when using Remoting the Ballon Tip never shows up. Of course neither does the console, so perhaps this is just a limitation of Remoting, that no UI can be triggered?

Any insights greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unsure why it takes so long but I suspect it maybe best to create the ps1 script and copy it to each of the systems and then remotely execute that.

Comment: Nick, I had thought about that, but when I run it "locally" it is still using the network file, so it would not seem to make a difference. BUT, I have some other code that is copied locally, so I'll add the resources needed for this as well and run a test. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get a UI to show up like that since the script won't be running in the interactive user's session.

As for performance, I'm not entirely sure why would it take such a drastically longer time.

First, I would say try to remote into your local machine (instead of just running it locally), by passing either `localhost`, `.`, or the actual local computer name to the `-ComputerName` parameter of `Invoke-Command`. See if the performance is still as bad, or how it differs.

I'm also wondering if it has to do with spawning another `powershell.exe` process on the remote side. In theory it shouldn't, but what if you do this instead:

```
Invoke-Command -computerName:$machine -argumentList: $file, $context –scriptblock {
    param (
        [String]$file,
        [string]$context
    )

    $sb = [ScriptBlock]::Create((Get-Content $file -Raw))
    & $sb -context:$context

} -credential:$credential -authentication:CredSSP –asJob -jobName:$machine > $null
```

Comment: Ah, bummer about the UI. It really is frustrating that their isn't a built in, secure and competent messaging system in Windows. As for the alternative approach, I tried that and it doesn't run at all. But I assume the fact that scripts are blocked on the target machine and thus -ExecutionPolicy Bypass is required might explain that? I also tried running locally, but that failure looks to be me not getting the revision right. All I did was change the machine name to '.'. Will experiment there some more.

Comment: Hmm, a little more data. When I did a different remoting job, done in admin context, I have no such performance issues. It's only the job running as a regular user that has the issues. But, the tasks that are REALLY slow are the Unpin & Pin to Taskbar stuff, which is usually a little slow, but now it's an order of magnitude slower. So, very curious if their the standard user or the Pin to task bar could be the issue. I may also try upgrading to a newer version of PS, as I am on 2.0 for these tests. Gonna be a long week I suspect. ;)